# Sleep in Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Usecase:
For my angularJS(1.6.4) application, I am writing unit test in jasmine.

In my test case, I call a poll() function which keeps calling another function CheckTaskStatus() repeatedly using $interval. I am spy-ing CheckTaskStatus() and want to check that it has been called a certain number of times. 
So after calling poll(), I want to be able to wait for some time and then check the the number of times CheckTaskStatus() is called using expect().

Problem:
I have been unable to find a way to make jasmine wait after call to poll() and before expect().

After poll() I have tried using below options, but those do not cause jasmine to sleep:

- $timeout
- settimeout
- async function which calls await on function returning promise. 
  **Service**
  import * as angular from 'angular';

export class Polling {
    public static $inject = ['$q', '$http', '$interval'];

```
constructor(private $q: ng.IQService, private $http, private $interval) {}

public poll(interval: number, pollFn: () => ng.IPromise<any>, until?: (any) => boolean, cancel?: ng.IPromise<any>) {
    let intervalPromise = null;
    const done = this.$q.defer();

    const intervalFn = () => {
        pollFn().then((pollFnResult) => {
            if (until && until(pollFnResult)) {
                this.$interval.cancel(intervalPromise);
                done.resolve();
            }
        }).catch(() => {});  
    };

    // Set up an interval to execute the pollFunction
    intervalPromise = this.$interval(intervalFn, interval);
    intervalPromise.catch(() => {});

    intervalFn();

    if (cancel) {
        cancel.then(() => {
            this.$interval.cancel(intervalPromise);
            done.resolve();
        })
            .catch(() => {}); 
    }

    return done.promise;
}
```

}

export default angular.module('myPolling', [])
    .service('polling', Polling).name;

**Jasmine test**

```html
fdescribe('myPolling module tests', () => {
    'use strict';
    let $rootScope,
        $q: ng.IQService,
        $http,
        $interval,
        $timeout;

    beforeEach(mockModule('myPolling'));
    beforeEach(() => {
        jasmine.clock().install();
    });
    beforeEach(inject((_$rootScope_, _$q_, _$http_, _$interval_, _polling_, _$timeout_) => {
        this.$rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        this.$q = _$q_;
        this.$http = _$http_;
        this.$interval = _$interval_;
        this.polling = _polling_;
        $timeout = _$timeout_;


    }));

    function sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }

    async function SleepForASecond() {
        await sleep(1050);
    }

    it('blah', () => {

        let pollCount = 0;
        let pollObj = {
            pollFn: () => {
                pollCount++;
                return this.$q.when(pollCount);
            }
        };
         // jasmine.createSpy('pollFn');
        spyOn(pollObj, 'pollFn').and.callThrough();

        let cancel = this.$q.defer();
        this.polling.poll(100, pollObj.pollFn, () => false, cancel.promise);
  
  // Need a mechanism to wait for a second.
  // SleepForASecond().then(() => { cancel.resolve(); });
  
        expect(pollObj.pollFn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(10);

    });

});
```

Comment: Please, provide your real code instead of some abstract situation. *I call a poll() function which keeps calling another function CheckTaskStatus() repeatedly using $interval* - this will likely be treated totally different than SleepForASecond async function.

Comment: Updated the description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AngularJS asynchronous code and arbitrary JS code are tested differently in Jasmine.

AngularJS services were designed specifically to make tests synchronous, including [`$interval`](https://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html#section-Jasmine_Clock):

> In tests you can use $interval.flush(millis) to move forward by millis milliseconds and trigger any functions scheduled to run in that time.

So it is:

```
let cancel = this.$q.defer();
this.polling.poll(100, pollObj.pollFn, () => false, cancel.promise);

$interval.flush(1050);
expect(pollObj.pollFn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(10);
```

It's different in tests that involve non-Angular asynchronous units. [Jasmine clock API](https://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html#section-Jasmine_Clock) should be used instead. It patches built-in timer functions in order to execute them synchronously with Jasmine `tick` method.

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jasmine.clock().install();
});

afterEach(() => {
  jasmine.clock().uninstall();
});

it('...', () => {
  SleepForASecond().then(() => {
    expect(1).toBe(0);
  });
  jasmine.clock().tick(1050);
});
```

Jasmine 2.7 [adds support](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/master/release_notes/2.7.0.md) for promises and `async` functions. This allows to seamlessly test promise-based functions, but promises will produce a real delay and result in asynchronous test:

```
it('...', async () => {
  await SleepForASecond();
  expect(1).toBe(0);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! @estus. That was very insightful. $interval.flush() worked for me.
I use Jasmine 2.8.0, so would I be able to use async functions?

Comment: Yes. But usually you won't need them in Angular tests (unless native promises are involved in application itself). Mixing $q promises with native ones (including `async`) may lead to bad situations, due to how $q works.

Comment: When I hit back button, I see that ‘intervalPromise.catch(() => {});’ is getting executed. However, in   Controllers onExit() function I am resolving cancel promise. This should have ideally cancelled the interval from cancel.then() block. But somehow doesn't. Any clues?

Comment: Also, would you advice on error handling best practises for Angular JS promises? It it wise to have the catch blocks ignore errors(I guess not)?

Comment: Yes, errors should always be caught. I'd recommend to use https://github.com/bvaughn/jasmine-promise-matchers . It provides neat assertions and handles errors as well.

Comment: Currently, when the controller which calls poll() method goes out of scope, because the of a different state transition(e.g back button) my intervalpromise gets in catch(). When I try to print the error message `intervalPromise.catch((e) => { console.log(e); })`, I see "canceled" getting printed on the console. Can you help me find what is causing interval promise to be rejected?
In the state's onExit() I am resolving the stop promise which is supposed to call interval.cancel.

Comment: When $interval interval is cancelled, it produces 'canceled' rejection. This is normal behaviour. This rejection isn't an error and should be filtered out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154481/discussion-between-phalgun-and-estus).

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the test case validation to wait using jasmine's Asynchronous Support.

Refer topic 'Asynchronous Support' under [Jasmine documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html)

In the above case mentioned, the test case should be changed to as below:

```
    //pass done as parameter to the 'it' call back function
    it('blah', function(done) {
       ...
       poll()
      // Mechanism for sleep
     SleepForASecond().then(function() {              
         expect();
         //jasmine will evaluate the test case only after done is called.
         done();
     });
    })
```

Comment: it causes the below failure:
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) basPolling module tests blah FAILED
        Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 2271 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 5.2PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) SLOW 5.271 secs: myPolling module tests blah